# expected string or buffer: Private Messages App

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make Private Message App for my website on django.

Models.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='Без теми', blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'повідомлення'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Повідомлення'
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def write(request):
    context = {}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    context['form'] = WriteMessage()
    if request.POST:
        write_form = WriteMessage(request.POST)
        if write_form.is_valid():
            cd = write_form.cleaned_data
            if User.objects.filter(username=cd['recipient']).exists():
                message = Message(sender = request.user, recipient=User.objects.get(username = cd['recipient']), title=cd['title'], body=cd['body'], sent_date=datetime.now)
                message.save()
                return redirect('/inbox/')
            else:
                context['errors'] = ["Not found user with this username"]
                return render(request, 'send_message.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'send_message.html', context)
```

And when I try to send the message, I get the error: `expected string or buffer`. But, when I send message from admin page - it works wonderful.

What I must do? Help me, please. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is replace `sent_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)` for `sent_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` and deleting `sent_date=datetime.now` from creating new object in views.py

It seems, that trouble was in different types of data in `DateField` into `models.py` and `datetime` module...